# Prove that $\frac{3n^2+1}{3n^2+2n+1}$ converges to 1 using only converging limit definition

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

> Prove that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{3n^2+1}{3n^2+2n+1}=1.$$

$$\frac{3n^2+1}{3n^2+2n+1}<1+\varepsilon $$

I have to prove it with just the definition of a converging series.

A similar example was:
$$ \frac{2n+4}{n^2+3n-1} $$ converges to 0.

And this is how I proved it:

$$\frac{2n+4}{n^2+3n-1}<\varepsilon $$
$$\frac{2\left(n+2\right)}{n\left(n+2\right)-n-1}<\varepsilon $$

$$\frac{2\left(n+2\right)}{n\left(n+2\right)-n-1}\le \frac{2\left(n+2\right)}{n\left(n+2\right)}<\varepsilon $$

$$\frac{2}{n}<\varepsilon $$

$$n_0=\frac{2}{\varepsilon }+1$$

But here I need a clue on how to do it, since I end up with:
$$\frac{3n^2+1}{3n^2+3}<1+\varepsilon $$

and that doesn't really help me in any way.

Comment: The idea is that when $x rightarrow \infty$, highest order terms prevail, so you can see that it goes to 1. Technically, since you say you can do that example, what about rewrite the original function to $1-\frac{2n}{3n^2+2n+1}$ and have a try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write your term in the form $$\frac{\left(3+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)}{\left(3+\frac{2}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)}$$
or we have $$\left|\frac{3n^2+1}{3n^2+2n+1}-1\right|=\frac{2n}{3n^2+2n+1}<\frac{2n}{3n^2}$$
can you proceed?
and thank you for the $-1$

Comment: I know I'm rather sounding dumb, but I still don't see on how it would give me the solution

Comment: The OP is asking for an $\epsilon$-$N$ proof. Writing in this form doesn't help.

Comment: but you know that you can give me the $-1$

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/ZDbpMoT.png I didn't give you a -1, that wouldn't be nice.Also I can proceed thank you, here is an upvote to further prove my point.

Answer (score 0):

$$|\frac{3n^2+1}{3n^2+2n+1}-1|=|\frac{3n^2+1-(3n^2+2n+1)}{3n^2+2n+1}|=\frac{2n}{3n^2+2n+1}<\frac{2n}{n^2}=\frac{2}{n}$$
Hence $an\rightarrow1\quad$For me It looked like you forget the 1 when you tried to proof that $an\rightarrow 1$

Answer (score 0):

Let $\varepsilon >0$ and take $N = \frac{1}{\varepsilon}$. Then $n > N$ implies $n>\frac{1}{\varepsilon}$, hence

$\displaystyle \varepsilon > \frac{1}{n} = \frac{n}{n^2} > \frac{2n}{3n^2}> \frac{2n}{3n^2+2n+1} = \bigg|\frac{3n^2+1}{3n^2+2n+1}-1\bigg|.$